# Proving that $f_n(x)=\frac{(x+1)^n-x^n-1}{x(x+1)}$ is strictly positive for odd integers $n\geq 5$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> Let $n\geq 5$ be an odd integer. I'd like to prove that the function $$f_n(x)=\frac{(x+1)^n-x^n-1}{x(x+1)}$$ is strictly positive on $\mathbb{R}$.

(I already figured out that the numerator is divisible by the denominator, so $f_n(x)$ is in fact a polynomial of degree $n-3$.

I tried to find the minimum by differentiation, but I have difficulty finding the location and the value of the minimum. Another thing I know is that $f_n(x)$ is palindromic, but it doesn't seem to give any inspirations. Does anyone have ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have
$$f_5(x) = 5(x^2 + x + 1) > 0, \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Second, for $k\ge 2$, let
\begin{align*}
 g_k(x) &:= f_{2k+3}(x) - f_{2k+1}(x)\\[5pt]
 &= \frac{(x + 1)^{2k + 3} - (x + 1)^{2k + 1} - x^{2k + 3} + x^{2k + 1}}{x(x + 1)}\\
 &= \frac{(x + 1)^{2k}[(x + 1)^3 - (x + 1)] - x^{2k}(x^3 - x)}{x(x + 1)}\\
 &= \frac{(x + 1)^{2k}x(x + 1)(x + 2) - x^{2k}x(x - 1)(x + 1)}{x(x + 1)}\\
 &= (x + 1)^{2k}(x + 2) - x^{2k}(x - 1).
\end{align*}
We can prove that $g_k(x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $-2 < x < 1$, clearly $g_k(x) \ge 0$.

If $x \le -2$, we have $g_k(x) = (1 - x)(-x)^{2k} - (-x - 2)(-x - 1)^{2k} \ge 0$ since $1 - x > - x - 2 \ge 0$
and $- x > - x - 1 \ge 1$.

If $x \ge 1$, we have $g_k(x) \ge 0$
since $x + 1 > x \ge 1$
and $x + 2 > x - 1 \ge 0$.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

I will treat $f$ as  polynomial of degree $n-3$.

If $f$ takes both positive and negative values then it must vanish at some point. But $(x+1)^{n}=x^{n}+1$ has no  solution in the real line other than $-1$ and $0$: Its derivative is strictly positive in $(-\frac 1 2 , \infty)$ and strictly negative in $(-\infty, -\frac 1  2 )$. So it attains its minimum at $-\frac  1 2$ and there are exactly two values at which it vanishes. Of course, these are $0$ and $-1$. Now $f_n(0)\neq 0$ since $x^{2}$ is not  factor of the numerator and $f_n(-1)\neq 0$ since $(1+x)^{2}$ is not  factor of the numerator. Hence, $f$ does not change sign. Also, $f(1)>0$ so $f(x) >0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Can you elaborate why $((x+1)^n-x^n)'>0$?

Comment: @richrow I have edited my answer. The minimum of the numerator is attained at $-\frac 1  2$.

Comment: @richrow Remember that $n-1$ is even so $n(x+1)^{n-1}-nx^{n-1} >0$ if and only if $(x+1)^{2}-x^{2} >0$ which means $x >-\frac 1 2 $.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that for all $x$ the inequality
$$
\frac{(x+1)^n-x^n-1}{x(x+1)}>0
$$
holds. Consider three cases:

- $x>0$. Then, $x(x+1)>0$ and
  $$
  (x+1)^n-x^n-1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x^k>0.
  $$
- $x<-1$. Denote $y=-x-1$, then $y>0$ and $x(x+1)>0$ and we need to check that
  $$
  \frac{(x+1)^n-x^n-1}{x(x+1)}=\frac{-y^n+(y+1)^n-1}{y(y+1)}>0.
  $$
  This is similar to the first case.
- $-1<x<0$. Denote $t=-x\in(0,1)$, Then, we have
  $$
  (x+1)^n-x^n-1=(1-t)^n+t^n-1<(t+(1-t))^n-1=0.
  $$
  Thus, $(x+1)^n-x^n-1<0$ while $x(x+1)<0$.

Comment: Note that $f_n(0),f_n(-1)\neq 0$ (if we treat $f_n$ as a polynomial) because we can take the limit in the first two cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but $f_n(0)$ and $f_n(-1)$ are not guaranteed to be nonzero in your proof, since taking limit not necessarily preserve strict positivity(or negativity).

Comment: I meant that those limits could be computed directly.